# load_set of dataset returning NoneType

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm getting an error from this python code

```py
filename = 'Flickr_8k.trainImages.txt'
train = load_set(filename)
print('Dataset: %d' % len(train))
train_descriptions = load_clean_description('Image_Caption_Project_Model_Data/descriptions.txt', train)
print('Descriptions: train=%d' % len(train_descriptions))
train_features = load_photo_features('Image_Caption_Project_Model_Data/features.pkl', train)
print('Photos: train=%d' % len(train_features))
train_descriptions
```

The error:

> ---> 38 print('Dataset: %d' % len(train))
>
> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

`train` should be `6000`, but is returning `NoneType`. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

one comment about the question writing:

as you can see the error is on line 38, there is no need for adding the following lines to the question, since they are redundant and confusing anyone trying to answer:

```
train_descriptions = load_clean_description('Image_Caption_Project_Model_Data/descriptions.txt', train)
print('Descriptions: train=%d' % len(train_descriptions))
train_features = load_photo_features('Image_Caption_Project_Model_Data/features.pkl', train)
print('Photos: train=%d' % len(train_features))
train_descriptions
```

anyway,
seems like your file is not loaded properly, so either it's not in the right format
or either the path\name is wrong.

MAKE SURE YOUR `Flickr_8k.trainImages.txt` FILE EXISTS IN THE SAME FOLDER THE SCRIPT IS.

it's hard to answer specific details since you didn't provide the `load_set` method, or library it is taken from

you can check if your file exists before like this

```
from os.path import exists

file_exists = exists(path_to_file)
```